# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'else'

Tags: python, jinja2

[image: enter image descrienter image description hereption here]
[image]
Iam trying to test the recommender with some random values which are not present in the list. My else part is not working and keeps throwing me an error

Can you please help how do fix the else part?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if %}
    {% for %} ... {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% else %}
```

has the `else` out of order. But for what you're trying to do, https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for shows an option that will do what you want.